# How can I make an AJAX request to a Highcharts rendering server running on a different port in production?

Tags: jquery, ajax, apache, highcharts, cors

I have some jQuery that makes a POST request to a PhantomJS server that runs on a different port (same IP).

When running the project locally, it would work fine.  In production however, I get a "Connection Refused" JS error.

The port in question is opened (tested by making a request with CURL).

I am enabling CORS in my apache config, but I seem to get the same result when it's not enabled.

[Here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/blob/master/exporting-server/phantomjs/highcharts-convert.js) is a link to the Phantom server file I'm attempting to POST to.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

The easiest way to get around the CORS restriction was to set up an apache proxy.

```
ProxyRequests off

<Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
</Proxy>

<Location /phantom>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
        ProxyPass http://localhost:3003/
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3003/
</Location>
```

So posting to `www.example.com/phantom` will forward the request to `http://localhost:3003/` and will yield a responds accordingly.